Foundry access keystore accounts from script
I've several accounts in Foundry keystore.
➜  foundry-contracts git:(main) ✗ cast wallet list

defaultKey (Local)
account1 (Local)
account2 (Local)
account3 (Local)


I need to access those account's keys in deployment script.
forge script script/Deploy.s.sol:Deploy --rpc-url $(BASE_SEPOLIA_RPC) --account account1 account2 account3 --broadcast --account account1 account2 account3 -vvvv

In the deployment script, this doesn't work.
uint256 contractorsPk = vm.envUint("ACCOUNT1_PRIVATE_KEY");
contractors = vm.addr(contractorsPk);

script failed: vm.envUint: environment variable "ACCOUNT1_PRIVATE_KEY" not found

How can I access account1 private key.
Note 1: I need that private key to transfer ERC20 tokens from account1 address to another contract.

I don't think it's possible because the entire idea of having the keystore in the first place is to avoid storing and entering the private key in plain text anywhere.
However, if you just want to reveal the private key for a corresponding keystore account, you can use the decrypt-keystore command of cast wallet, like:
cast wallet decrypt-keystore account1

Then, store the private key as an environment variable in the .env file.
.env
ACCOUNT1_PRIVATE_KEY=0x..............

You can now use the private key stored as the environment variable in your script with vm.envUint, just like you're currently doing.

Yea you’re right, I had to extract private key from keystore in deployment script.
